# Dynamically created controls within TableLayoutPanel: How to access events or create custom ones?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a TableLayoutPanel that on my form, named `tlpSSMappings`. I am populating it based on columns in a data table that I store in memory via a foreach loop. Here is my code currently:

```
tlpSSMappings.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
tlpSSMappings.RowCount = 0;
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    tlpSSMappings.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
    // For Add New Row (Loop this code for add multiple rows)
    if (tlpSSMappings.RowCount == 1)
    {
        //tlpSSMappings.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = col.ToString() }, 3, tlpSSMappings.RowCount-1);
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { DataSource = configFields }, 1, tlpSSMappings.RowCount-1 );
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() { Text = "Mapped" },2, tlpSSMappings.RowCount - 1);
        tlpSSMappings.RowCount = tlpSSMappings.RowCount + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        List<string> copyOfConfigDS = new List<string>();
        foreach (string cfg in configFields)
        {
            copyOfConfigDS.Add(cfg);
        }
        ComboBox c = new ComboBox()
        {
            DataSource = copyOfConfigDS,                            
        };

        CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox()
        {
            Text = "Mapped"
        };

        tlpSSMappings.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = col.ToString() }, 3, tlpSSMappings.RowCount-1);
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(c, 1, tlpSSMappings.RowCount-1);
        tlpSSMappings.Controls.Add(chkBox, 2, tlpSSMappings.RowCount - 1);
        tlpSSMappings.RowCount = tlpSSMappings.RowCount + 1;
    }        
}
```

You can see that there are 3 controls per row in `tlpSSMappings` being created, 1 ComboBox, 1 Label and 1 Checkbox.

I wish to have code that works as such: When I change the value of a combobox, the checkbox within that row will automatically be checked. How can I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you gave your items names, you could refer to them by finding control by name, or, if you kept hold  of the variables creating the new components, you could access them just like any other control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach an event handler to each comboBox and set IsChecked property of related checkBox

```
ComboBox c = new ComboBox()
{
    DataSource = copyOfConfigDS,                            
};

CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox()
{
    Text = "Mapped"
};

c.SelectedIndexChanged += (eventSender, args) => 
{
    chkBox.IsChecked = c.SelectedIndex >= 0;
};
```

Comment: This looks right, but the syntax after the += is not right. What am I missing, I wonder....

Comment: @DillonWillis, i forgot semicolon after lambda expression. and maybe variable names were used already

Comment: There it goes! I missed that too. THank you!

Comment: @DillonWillis, nice! you also need to use this code in `if-then` branch, not only in `if-else`. or maybe refactor method a bit to avoid code duplication :\